# Deleting the roots parent in a binary searach tree - Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, binary-search-tree

So I have a binary tree fully working, The values stored in each node are as follows:

```
 public Node(Comparable data) {
                this.data = data;
                parent = null;
                left = null;
                right = null;
            }
```

If I want to delete the root and make either the left or right child the root, I need to set the root as left/right child, then make the parent null.

The only time this will occur is when either all of the left nodes are empty and the root is the smallest, same goes for the right side.

This is what I have tried but it throws a nullPointerException.

```
root = root.getLeft();
root.setParent(null);
```

I ave all necessary getters and setters.

Comment: probably the left child of the old root is null. In this case you can just check and don't call the setter. In the other possibile case, the old root itself is null, well, there is nothing to do.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check if it has the left node/child.
I do not know the getter/setter code but I assume that the get code does not handle exception.
So in short you need to check if it has the left node..call get code only if it is not null.